# Have seen a code in a CSS content property that I can't understand where it is defined

Tags: css, styles, pseudo-element

I'm looking at some code which has the following content property value for a pseudeo element - "\e90c". I understand this is some sort of escape code which represents a character or icon but where can I find what this icon would be? I haven't found an example of it online.
I did find some links which showed me a paint-format icon but it's not that.

I don't know css codes very well so I'm not sure how it works or where it would be coming from.

Updated - The font-family being used is icomoon, but I couldn't understand how it's working after reading through their site.

Comment: it's could depending on used font

Comment: If that is a Unicode codepoint then it points to a glyph in the Private Use Area, U+E000 to U+FFFF.  So it is user-defined and there is little else we can say about it.

Comment: @BoarGules how can you tell when you see the code if it refers to Unicode or if it could be user defined or related to a font? any tips to investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deppending on
the font used.

example:  in the case of case of **Mozilla Foundation Icon Font**
=> simply test it :

```css
p:after {
  font-family : 'foundation-icons';
  font-size   : 4em;
  content     : "\e90c"; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://mozilla.github.io/foundation-icons/assets/foundation-icons.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<p> and your icone is (in foundation-icons font ): </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the font connection? so does the code value in content always refer to the font being used? how can one tell if the code refers to a font or unicode as someone else has posted that these escape codes can also refer to glyphs and other icons etc in the unicode list. This is what confused me in investigating.

Comment: I saw the font-family being used is icomoon, I looked at their documentation but not clear how to find \ec90

Comment: @jobe it is a vast subject, impossible to cover by comment here.
The world of fonts / icons has its own languages (yes, it's plural) and it's full of traps. Each OS privileges its font system (TrueType / WOFF / WOFF2 / EOT / SVG) which forces the web page to juggle with it.
For the icons in the range [U + E000 to U + FFFF] the assignment of utf8 codes is free and does not follow any rule -

Comment: So if I know the font family is icomoon and I know the code is \ec90 how can I tell what icon that code refers to? I couldn't find it on their page but I will look again. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @jobe it's not really meant to be found, you have to use your browser's debugger. Otherwise, from one version to another a utf-8 code can be changed and it is preferable to always use the className. Some icon svg are not associated with a character because it is added dynamically by JS code

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it helped but I'm still confused, if you can suggest a good article for understanding this that would be great.

Comment: @jobe maybe that,https://mediatemple.net/blog/design-creative/creating-implementing-icon-font-tutorial/ ? but that assumes you know a bit about SVG

Answer (score 1):

That Unicode Symbol can be used as an icon if you display it in the right font. See https://mozilla.github.io/foundation-icons/ for example.

Comment: please consider adding some examples with your answer besides the reference link.

Comment: Apologies I didn't know about the font connection, I thought "\e90c" would be a fixed icon.